# YOAST SEO settings for permalinks

Tags: seo, wordpress

I'm using YOAST seo plugin, i found a small issue, in the snippet URL it shows the URL as

abcd.com/p=32?.

Why it does not show full URL like how it comes in search engine?. How to change this permalink i need something like

abcd.com/10/22/how-to-run.html.

Comment: What do you have set for your Settings > Permalinks?

Comment: i have kept them blank, and by default its showing by appending p=some number after URL. what i need to update to avoide

Comment: Hi,i just noticed wired behavior,i'm really not sure this is how it works or not. Actually i created a post and saved it in draft and again i re-open the same post for that URL is appearing properly, before i put into draft URL looks like this i.e abcd.com/p=32?. After saving and reopening the same post URL looks like this abc.com/10/12/how-to-catch.html... is it happening like this for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the SEO Yoast settings.  Instead:

1. Go to Settings >> Permalinks
2. Use one of those common settings, depending on which one you like
3. Or use a custom structure like /%category%/%postname%/

That will change your permalinks.  As far as serving up static html pages, you'll need to install a caching plugin such as W3 Total Cache, WP Super Cache, or something ... (there are other caching plugins like DB Cache Reloaded Fix and Hyper Cache, but I'm less familiar with 'em).

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes in default permalink settings i have modified as you suggested but YOST overrides the default settings i guess so... i need to do something like this /%category%/%postname%/ in permalink or some other column, i m very new to this..

Comment: For my Yoast settings .... SEO >> Permalinks, I have the first 4 boxes checked, and the 5th box unchecked.  But getting your permalinks to be canonical is accomplished in the way I described.  Joost's plugin won't override anything.  Can you tell me what your URL is?

Comment: Hi,i just noticed wired behavior,i'm really not sure this is how it works or not. Actually i created a post and saved it in draft and again i re-open the same post for that URL is appearing properly, before i put into draft URL looks like this i.e abcd.com/p=32?. After saving and reopening the same post URL looks like this abc.com/10/12/how-to-catch.html... is it happening like this for you?

Comment: Yeah ... once you save it as a draft or publish it, the permalink will switch to the one you want it to be.

Comment: Ok, but why it will not show at the time of post creation, any settings we need to alter to get it reflect during the creation of post?

Comment: That really has nothing to do with Joost's plugin ... that's just how core WordPress works, if I'm understanding correctly.  You don't have to actually publish the post.  If you want to get a sneak peek of your permalink, just tick "save draft" and that will do it (unless you change your categories around).  You could write 'em on Github.

Comment: Oh, ok but when i publish automatically URL will be created na, that's fine.. Thanks lot for your support

Comment: Hey, i'm facing one more issue. My blog post are not getting indexed in Google. how to ping them to google once i write post?

Comment: Just use a service like ping-o-matic ... http://pingomatic.com/ ...  and then log into your Google Webmaster Tools and do a Fetch as Google.

Comment: I tried the ways you suggested and waited for 2 days, still my blog posts are not indexed, i don no whats wrong with settings. can you please tell me any mandatory settings which needs to be on?. i'm pretty new to this, do i need to submit sitemap in Google webmaster or Yost plugin does automatically?

Comment: Yoast will make a sitemap_index.xml and a few others.  Then you go to Google Webmaster Tools >> Optimize >> Sitemaps ... and submit the sitemaps there.  Submit sitemap_index.xml, post-sitemap.xml, page-sitemap.xml, category-sitemap.xml, and if you want, attachment-sitemap.xml, and post_tag-sitemap.xml.  Google will make you download a verification file that you upload to your root -- do it, verify them (you'll only have to do it once), and submit that sitemap.  I also use a regular Google sitemap.xml --> http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/

Comment: Submit them all to google's webmaster tools, and also Bing Webmaster Tools ... all of the sitemaps.  Bing will make you download a verification file also.  Then you can go to www.pingomatic.com and ping 'em, too ... things will get crawled shortly.

Comment: Thanks Jason, your tip worked, but i want to learn some more, when i google my URL techpopular.com. i'm able to see a slash("\") next to my domain i.e it looks like this techpopular.com\. I dont no how this "\" came. Also i have enabled breadcumbs, but i'm not able to see them in search results. One more thing i.e when i google i'm able to see categories but description is appearing like site description. is it good to keep or remove it?. kindly help

Comment: You can just e-mail me .... jasonpaulweber at gmail.com ... it may be recommended over cluttering SE with comments.  I'll be able to elaborate more there.  Trailing slashes are definitely a problem; they can be construed as duplicate content by G.  If you're talking about breadcrumbs like home >> services >> products >> product A ... your SERPS just don't show up like that in G.  You may be referring to sitelinks ("sublinks" underneath your links), which are a G mystery.  Just keep up w/ the content and G will make their own sitelinks with time.  Difficult to control.  E-mail me if more ?'s ..

Comment: Thanks Jason, i will email you shortly, thanks lot for sharing ur id.

Comment: I received a chat request, but no e-mail ... unless it went to my SPAM and didn't realize it.